# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError doesn't work for java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: java, memory

I use -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=\"kill -9 %p\". It works for most of out of memory cases, but it doesn't kill the process for java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread.

Comment: Can you share any more details on the issue?  What types of application you are running this in, exception details, etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may well be that the system cannot handle any more threads.  That, unfortunately, would also mean that no new processes can be created - but the `kill` command would run as a new process!  A rather unpleasant Catch-22...