# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread Threads: 6347 total

Tags: linux, maven, maven-3, go-cd

I am getting `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread Threads` exception while trying to run my go cd pipeline. When I ran `top -H` command I seen `Threads: 6350 total,   1 running, 6345 sleeping,   3 stopped,   1 zombie`! This is clearly waaaaaaaay to many especially I see other build severs only have `Threads: 359 total,   1 running, 358 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie`

I seen the following posts but I'm not sure they apply as they are code implementation and asking how to kill threads respectively:

[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3500773/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-create-new-native-thread)
[-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError doesn't work for java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23373117/xxonoutofmemoryerror-doesnt-work-for-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-unable-to-cr)

My question is there a way to clean up all the sleeping threads? There are roughly about 20 times the amount?

Build logs:

```
22:37:48.789 [go] Job Started: 2020-08-25 22:37:48 UTC

22:37:48.789 [go] Start to prepare PATGUI-build/132/Execute_Script/1/build_job on edipgo-po-b4p.sys.comcast.net [/app/go-agent1]
22:37:48.794 [go] Start to update materials.

22:37:48.794 [go] Start updating files at revision 1c9e6a31946f62af1285305f338178d2a8fd13f2 from git@example.com:TPP-Provisioning/PortOutGui.git
22:37:48.801 Cloning into '/app/go-agent1/pipelines/PATGUI-build'...
22:38:00.435 [GIT] Fetching changes
22:38:01.640 [GIT] Performing git gc
22:38:01.743 [GIT] Reset working directory pipelines/PATGUI-build
22:38:01.743 [GIT] Cleaning all unversioned files in working copy
22:38:01.953 [GIT] Cleaning submodule configurations in .git/config
22:38:02.056 [GIT] Updating working copy to revision 1c9e6a31946f62af1285305f338178d2a8fd13f2
22:38:02.413 HEAD is now at 1c9e6a3 correcting object creation methods
22:38:02.517 [GIT] Removing modified files in submodules
22:38:02.716 [GIT] Updating git sub-modules
22:38:12.506 [GIT] Cleaning unversioned files and sub-modules
22:38:12.506 [GIT] Git sub-module status
22:38:12.583  51c608012d468edce285f7e60084b5dfa8e87a7a trunk (PAT-9.10@79-997-g51c6080)
22:38:12.584 [GIT] Cleaning all unversioned files in working copy
22:38:12.901 [go] Done.

22:38:12.902 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_SERVER_URL' to value 'https://edipgo-po-b1p.sys.comcast.net:8154/go'
22:38:12.902 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_TRIGGER_USER' to value 'cdvprov'
22:38:12.902 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_PIPELINE_NAME' to value 'PATGUI-build'
22:38:12.902 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_PIPELINE_COUNTER' to value '132'
22:38:12.902 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_PIPELINE_LABEL' to value '132'
22:38:12.902 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_STAGE_NAME' to value 'Execute_Script'
22:38:12.902 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_STAGE_COUNTER' to value '1'
22:38:12.902 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_JOB_NAME' to value 'build_job'
22:38:12.902 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_REVISION_SOURCE' to value '1c9e6a31946f62af1285305f338178d2a8fd13f2'
22:38:12.902 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_TO_REVISION_SOURCE' to value '1c9e6a31946f62af1285305f338178d2a8fd13f2'
22:38:12.902 [go] setting environment variable 'GO_FROM_REVISION_SOURCE' to value '1c9e6a31946f62af1285305f338178d2a8fd13f2'

22:38:12.910 [go] Start to build PATGUI-build/132/Execute_Script/1/build_job on edipgo-po-b4p.sys.comcast.net [/app/go-agent1]
22:38:12.911 [go] Current job status: passed.

22:38:12.911 [go] Start to execute task: Plugin with ID: script-executor.
22:38:12.952 [script-executor] OS detected: 'Linux'. Is Windows? false
22:38:12.963 [script-executor] Script written into '/app/go-agent1/pipelines/PATGUI-build/2f0ed637-c699-472a-8abd-d843898af4b9.sh'.
22:38:12.968 +++ date +%m
22:38:12.969 ++ BUILD_MONTH=08
22:38:12.970 +++ date +%m
22:38:12.971 ++ echo BUILD_MONTH=08
22:38:12.972 +++ cat pom.xml
22:38:12.972 +++ grep '<version>'
22:38:12.972 +++ head -1
22:38:12.973 +++ cut -d '>' -f2
22:38:12.973 +++ cut -d '<' -f1
22:38:12.975 ++ APP_VERSION=20.01
22:38:12.976 +++ cat pom.xml
22:38:12.976 +++ grep '<sprintNumber>'
22:38:12.976 +++ head -1
22:38:12.977 +++ cut -d '>' -f2
22:38:12.977 +++ cut -d '<' -f1
22:38:12.979 ++ SPRINT_NUMBER=01
22:38:12.979 ++ PATCH_NUMBER=132
22:38:12.979 ++ echo APP_VERSION=20.01
22:38:12.979 ++ echo PATCH_NUMBER=20.01.01.132
22:38:12.979 ++ /app/platform/apache-maven-3.0.3/bin/mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true -DbuildNumber=132 clean install
22:38:13.208 Error occurred during initialization of VM
22:38:13.208 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
22:38:13.212 [script-executor] Script completed with exit code: 1.
22:38:13.226 [go] Current job status: failed.

22:38:13.229 [go] Start to create properties PATGUI-build/132/Execute_Script/1/build_job on edipgo-po-b4p.sys.comcast.net [/app/go-agent1]
22:38:13.229 [go] Start to upload PATGUI-build/132/Execute_Script/1/build_job on edipgo-po-b4p.sys.comcast.net [/app/go-agent1]
22:38:13.232 [go] The rule [PortOutApp/target/*ear] cannot match any resource under [pipelines/PATGUI-build]
22:38:13.246 [go] Uploading artifacts from /app/go-agent1/pipelines/PATGUI-build/build-vars to target/
22:38:13.266 [go] Uploading finished. Failed to upload [PortOutApp/target/*ear]
22:38:13.281 [go] Job completed PATGUI-build/132/Execute_Script/1/build_job on exmaple-po-b4p.sys.comcast.net [/app/go-agent1]
```

Comment: Really using /app/platform/apache-maven-3.0.3/bin/mvn ? more or less 10 year old Maven ? Out of native threads means the machine on it running is overloaded...to many things running on that machine...

Comment: Hi @khmarbaise, yes the application is written on an old framework called Beehive... back in 04'/05'. Very very old. Can we see the lifespan on threads and kill old ones perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer so to speak but I resolved it by restarting linux machine by running shutdown -r now command and cleared the threads.